# How to mock parameterized method in codeception framework

Tags: unit-testing, zend-framework2, codeception, phpunit

I have one parameterized method which accept string parameter and returns data upon passed param. I am using codeception framework for writing unit testing for php-zend project.

Method: `getDataByView($view)`  `$view` can be default, all.

So I want mock this method such way it behave & return result based on passed params. I didnt get way in codeception framework so used phpunit code for that. But getting problems in that.

```
$map = array(
            array('default', $default),
            array('all', $all)
        );

$mock = $this->getMockBuilder('ViewTable')
        ->setMethods(['getDataByView'])
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();

$mock->expects($this->any())
        ->method('getDataByView')
        ->will($this->returnValueMap($map));
```

Actually this code work as per my expectation. Since I am using `setMethods()` it calls the ViewTable class constructor. If I dont use `setMethods` then It doesn't call constructor.

**Problems:**

- I want to mock only one method of class, so I have used
  `setMethods()` but it calls mock class constructor. I dont want that.
  How can it be solved in phpunit.
- How to mock parameterized method in codeception framework.